# Constraint changes of super view not reflecting in sub views

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

**Objective:**

I have 4 views arranged one below the other. The views also consists of subViews. 
Suppose the views are named say **A**, **B**, **C** and **D** in the order they are arranged. 
At a time, I need to show only, either **B** or **C**.

**Implementation:**

- Used `autolayout` to add respective constraints via `storyboard`.
- Created `NSLayoutConstraint` outlets for `Height constraints` of views **B** and **C**.
- Changed the `constant` property of the constraint outlet when required, say as follows:

  ```
  _heightConstraintOfC.constant = ORGINAL_VALUE_OF_C;
  _heightConstraintOfB.constant = 0.00;
  ```

  and

  ```
  _heightConstraintOfB.constant = ORGINAL_VALUE_OF_B;
  _heightConstraintOfC.constant = 0.00;
  ```

**What I Get:**

The views are behaving as expected, But when I change the `height constant` to `zero`, the subviews remain in the same position, behind the new overlapped view.

[image]

In the screen shot, Login button lies within view **B**, but is visible, even though view **C** overlaps it.

**What I Tried:**

I tried hiding the views , i.e. hide **B** when showing **C**. This works, but doesn't seem to be the right way when using `autolayout`.

I also tried using

`[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`, `[self.view layoutSubviews]` and `[self.view setNeedsLayout]`. This didn't help.

What I understand is that you need to add constraints to everything within a view and then update each of them manually. This doesn't seem feasible to me.

Please provide your valuable suggestions or a solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Try setting your views' clipsToBounds property to yes, so the subviews won't show outside the bounds (which will be zero height).

Comment: @rdelmar thanks! That did solve the problem. If possible, Can you please explain why the the autolayout approach didn't work, even though I had set the constraints for all sub views?

Comment: set the content compression resistance of the view that you don't want to see to a low value, then it should disappear.

Comment: @jimpic tried it. but the view still appears as in the image.